# Did I correctly account for daylight savings time in this code?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, pytz

So I'm pulling data from a druid database for a given time period. For example:

```
time_from = '2020-11-26T06:00:00'
time_to = '2020-11-29T06:00:00'
```

Between those times^.
However, depending on the day, the time is either MST (MOUNTAIN standard time) or MDT (MOUNTAIN daylight savings time), which determines the -06:00 or -07:00 at the end.

Is the following code a correct way for accounting for daylight savings time?

```
 from datetime import datetime
import pytz #must run 'pip install pytz'


#ENTER TIMES HERE FOR MAIN.PY
time_from_1='2020-11-26T06:00:00'
time_to_1='2020-11-29T06:00:00'


#CHECKING MST/MDT AND UPDATING TIMES IF NECESSARY
naive = datetime.strptime(time_from_1, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
mountain = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
time_from_aware = mountain.localize(naive, is_dst=None) 
naive = datetime.strptime(time_to_1, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
mountain = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
time_to_aware = mountain.localize(naive, is_dst=None) 


def is_dst(aware_dt):
    assert aware_dt.tzinfo is not None
    assert aware_dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(aware_dt) is not None
    return bool(aware_dt.dst())

if is_dst(time_from_aware)==True:
    time_from=time_from_1+'-06:00'
else:
    time_from=time_from_1+'-07:00'
    
if is_dst(time_to_aware)==True:
    time_to=time_to_1+'-06:00'
else:
    time_to=time_to_1+'-07:00'  

print(time_from)
print(time_to)
```

Comment: First of all, don't use pytz. We have 2021, Python 3.9 and [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). Secondly, [don't use utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/tag/datetime.html), use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` instead to avoid the pitfalls of naive datetime.

Comment: I'm using an older python version. Also edited my code a bit ago and uploaded it just now. Does this avoid the naive datetime problem?

Comment: Why are you appending the offset yourself? The library should handle that for you.  Also, unless you can state clearly what *isn't* working, Stack Overflow isn't the best place to ask this sort of question.  Instead, consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a function in the library I should use that handles the offset? Thanks!

Comment: In principle, as Matt commented, you don't handle DST transitions on your own. The library does that for you. You can use [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) instead, as it will make the transition to `zoneinfo` easier.